A circular reference has been detected when serializing the object of class Symfony error
I am reaching out because I am encountering a circular reference issue. I am using version 7 of the symfony framework I have tried to implement several solutions, such as the attribute: #[MaxDepth(2)]. I have also set up DTOs to avoid this kind of problem, but despite everything, when I try to return JSON, I encounter this error:
if ($filterParams['country'] != 'FR' || $filterParams['region'] || $filterParams['cityOrZip']) {
        $alerts = $alertRepository->findByFilters($filterParams);
    } else {
        $alerts = $alertRepository->findAlertsByCoordinates($north, $south, $east, $west, $filterParams);
    }
    
    $returnedData = [];
    
    foreach ($alerts as $item) {
        $cardHtml = $this->renderView('alert/partials/_card.html.twig', ['alert' => $item]);
        $returnedData[] = [$this->alertTransformer->transform($item), $cardHtml];
    }
    
    return $this->json($returnedData);

This is my Alert Entity :
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: AlertRepository::class)]
class Alert
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'uuid', unique: true)]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'CUSTOM')]
    #[ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class: UuidGenerator::class)]
    private ?UuidInterface $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $type = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $title = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'text', nullable: true)]
    private ?string $description = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'datetime_immutable', nullable: true)]
    private ?\DateTimeImmutable $date_of_loss = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $state = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'datetime_immutable')]
    private ?\DateTimeImmutable $created_at = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'datetime_immutable', nullable: true)]
    private ?\DateTimeImmutable $updated_at = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Address::class, cascade: ['persist'], fetch: 'EAGER', inversedBy: 'alerts')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    #[MaxDepth(2)]
    private ?Address $location = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: User::class, inversedBy: 'alerts')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    #[MaxDepth(2)]
    private ?User $owner = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Animal::class, fetch: 'EAGER', inversedBy: 'alerts')]
    #[MaxDepth(2)]
    private ?Animal $animal = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $specie = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'alert', targetEntity: AlertPhoto::class, cascade: ['persist', 'remove'], fetch: 'EAGER')]
    private Collection $photos;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $status = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'text', nullable: true)]
    private ?string $additional_information = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'float', nullable: true)]
    private ?float $bonus = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->photos = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->created_at = new \DateTimeImmutable();
    }

This is my address entity :
class Address
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'uuid', unique: true)]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'CUSTOM')]
    #[ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class: UuidGenerator::class)]
    private ?UuidInterface $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank(message: "Le champ nom est obligatoire.")]
    private ?string $name = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $address_line_1 = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $address_line_2 = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank(message: "Le champ ville est obligatoire.")]
    private ?string $city = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank(message: "Le champ état ou région est obligatoire.")]
    private ?string $state_or_region = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 15)]
    #[Assert\Regex(
        pattern: "/^\d{5}$/",
        message: "Le code postal doit être un nombre à 5 chiffres."
    )]
    private ?string $postal_code = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank(message: "Le champ pays est obligatoire.")]
    private ?string $country = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Assert\Choice(
        choices: ['personal', 'professional', 'animal'],
        message: "Le type doit être l'un des suivants : personal, professional, animal."
    )]
    private ?string $type = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'address', targetEntity: User::class)]
    #[MaxDepth(2)]
    private Collection $owner_id;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'address', targetEntity: Animal::class)]
    #[MaxDepth(2)]
    private Collection $animal_id;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'location', targetEntity: Alert::class)]
    #[MaxDepth(2)]
    private Collection $alerts;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'float', nullable: true)]
    private ?float $latitude = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'float', nullable: true)]
    private ?float $longitude = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $department = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->alerts = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->owner_id = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->animal_id = new ArrayCollection();
    }


and this is my User entity :
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'uuid', unique: true)]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'CUSTOM')]
    #[ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class: UuidGenerator::class)]
    private UuidInterface $id;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 180, unique: true)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Assert\Email]
    private ?string $email = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private array $roles = [];

    #[Assert\NotBlank(message: 'Votre mot de passe ne peut pas être vide.', groups: ["create"])]
    #[Assert\Length(
        min: 8,
        max: 50,
        minMessage: 'Votre mot de passe doit contenir au moins {{ limit }} caractères.',
        maxMessage: 'Votre mot de passe ne peut pas dépasser {{ limit }} caractères.'
    )]
    private ?string $plain_password;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string')]
    private string $password;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Assert\Length(
        min: 2,
        max: 50,
        minMessage: 'Votre prénom doit contenir au moins {{ limit }} caractères.',
        maxMessage: 'Votre prénom ne peut pas dépasser {{ limit }} caractères.'
    )]
    private string $first_name;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 50)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Assert\Length(
        min: 2,
        max: 50,
        minMessage: 'Votre nom de famille doit contenir au moins {{ limit }} caractères.',
        maxMessage: 'Votre nom de famille ne peut pas dépasser {{ limit }} caractères.'
    )]
    private string $last_name;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
    private ?\DateTimeImmutable $email_verified_at = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 25)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Assert\Choice(
        choices: ['Particular', 'Association']
    )]
    private string $account_type;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?\DateTimeImmutable $created_at = null;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
    private ?\DateTimeImmutable $updated_at = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 25)]
    #[Assert\Choice(
        choices: ['created', 'checked', 'banned', 'deleted', 'disabled'],
        message: 'Le status du compte n\'est pas valide.'
    )]
    private ?string $account_status = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'owner', targetEntity: Animal::class)]
    #[MaxDepth(2)]
    private Collection $animals;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(cascade: ['persist', 'remove'], fetch: 'EAGER', inversedBy: 'owner_id')]
    #[MaxDepth(2)]
    private ?Address $address = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 25, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $phone = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 25)]
    #[Assert\Choice(
        choices: ['Homme', 'Femme', 'Non-binaire' ],
        message: 'La valeur pour le genre n\'est pas valide. 
        Seules les valeurs suivantes sont acceptées : homme, femme, non-binaire.'
    )]
    #[Groups(['read:user', 'write:user'])]
    private ?string $gender = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATE_IMMUTABLE, nullable: true)]
    private ?\DateTimeImmutable $birthday = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'owner', targetEntity: Alert::class)]
    #[MaxDepth(2)]
    private Collection $alerts;

    #[Vich\UploadableField(mapping: 'user_image', fileNameProperty: 'imageName', size: 'imageSize')]
    private ?File $imageFile = null;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
    private ?string $imageName = null;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
    private ?int $imageSize = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'boolean')]
    private bool $isVerified = false;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'user', targetEntity: UserImage::class, cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    private Collection $images;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'user', targetEntity: AlertLinkUser::class, orphanRemoval: true)]
    private Collection $alertLinkUsers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->created_at = new \DateTimeImmutable();
        $this->updated_at = new \DateTimeImmutable();
        $this->animals = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->alerts = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->images = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->alertLinkUsers = new ArrayCollection();
    }

This is the alertDTO but the error is same when i use that:
class AlertDTO
{
    public ?string $id;
    public ?string $type;
    public ?string $title;
    public ?string $description;
    public ?\DateTimeImmutable $date_of_loss;
    public ?string $state;
    public ?\DateTimeImmutable $created_at;
    public ?\DateTimeImmutable $updated_at;
    public ?AddressDTO $location;
    public ?UserDTO $owner;
    public ?AnimalDTO $animal;
    public ?string $specie;
    public array $photos = [];
    public ?string $status;
    public ?string $additional_information;
    public ?float $bonus;

    public function __construct(
        ?string $id,
        ?string $type,
        ?string $title,
        ?string $description,
        ?\DateTimeImmutable $date_of_loss,
        ?string $state,
        ?\DateTimeImmutable $created_at,
        ?\DateTimeImmutable $updated_at,
        ?AddressDTO $location,
        ?UserDTO $owner,
        ?AnimalDTO $animal,
        ?string $specie,
        array $photos,
        ?string $status,
        ?string $additional_information,
        ?float $bonus
    ) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->type = $type;
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->description = $description;
        $this->date_of_loss = $date_of_loss;
        $this->state = $state;
        $this->created_at = $created_at;
        $this->updated_at = $updated_at;
        $this->location = $location;
        $this->owner = $owner;
        $this->animal = $animal;
        $this->specie = $specie;
        $this->photos = $photos;
        $this->status = $status;
        $this->additional_information = $additional_information;
        $this->bonus = $bonus;
    }
}

Thank you in advance for any leads or solutions you may provide.

exclude $alertLinkUsers from the user entity #[ignore]. Alert has Owner/User -> User has Allerts Circle Complete. Readup on serialization groups to only get needed information without circular references.

Thank you I think I will set up groups for serialization I found a temporary means created a pseudo dto but not solid for the long term.
